No module named apt_pkg
So, I was updating my ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 yesterday. I left it on updating and when I woke up I found that the laptop had turned off due to low power. I wasn't able to run ubuntu on my system after charging it.
I immediately switched to recovery mode and accessed the root shell. There, I tried to run the command sudo apt update but I am getting the error - No module named apt_pkg as shown in the image.

How to solve this issue ?

The system warns you to have power connected early in the release-upgrade process for a reason. If the process didn't complete; the system can be in an unknown state if power was lost & no-one was monitoring the system. I'd normally restore data from backups & start again OR non-destructively re-install the system (using 22.04) if it's a desktop install, as working out where it was up to maybe time consuming. What's best for you is up to you (you mention only release details; not the type of system), but I suggest you read messages & action them (ie. power connection!) in future.

This question is similar to: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'" appears in various commands. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.   Please read my prior comment, as you likely have multiple problems on your system due to power loss; this duplicate will only help with one of the issues; thus my prior comment suggestions

An interrupted release-upgrade during downloading is easy to fix.
An interrupted release-upgrade during installation is about the worst thing you can to your system short of physical destruction of the hardware. Sometimes it is easy to fix. Sometimes it is impossible to fix. Depends what was being installed at the moment of interruption, and what was left dangling.
Your output suggests a situation leaning toward 'impossible', or at least not worthwhile. The error means that the version of Python3 installed no longer matches the required bindings for apt.  An expert might be able to laboriously troubleshoot and fix it...if nothing else is wrong. It is likely safer and faster to reinstall Ubuntu.
Advice: Use a friend's machine to create a 24.04 Live USB. Boot into the "Try Ubuntu" environment. Backup your data to some other media. Then reinstall Ubuntu.
